# Determine if string format is "May 16, 2013" or UNIX Timestamp with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, date, data-cleaning

Doing some data wrangling with a large dataset. The data has a "date" field that randomly switches between a format like "1370039735000" and "May 16, 2013". So far I've converted other date fields with either

```
new Date("May 16, 2013")
```

or

```
new Date(NumberLong(1370039735000))
```

**How can I tell the difference between the two using regex or some other means?** I'm using MongoDB but it's all Javascript.

Comment: Can you not use MongoDB's query `$type` operator to check if it's a date or timestamp field?

Comment: @hwnd I couldn't use $type because all the data comes to me as a String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a unix timestamp, it's numbers only, and if it's not, it's an actual string (not empty or boolean) and javascript has a function for that, [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```
isNaN(datestring_or_number)
```

can be easily used

```
new Date(isNaN(str) ? str : NumberLong(str));
```

Answer (score 2):

From your post, I assume you are **absolutely 100% certain** that these are the only two possible formats. If it is not the case then comment/edit your post.

Testing if the date contains a letter should seal the deal in a simple manner.

```
/[a-z]/i.test("May 16, 2013") // true, the date is written out
/[a-z]/i.test(1370039735000) // false, it's unix epoch format
```

Comment: That's... not what his post says at all, and it's clearly not his intention. It says "a format like...". How could that mean what you're suggesting it means?

Comment: @ColinDeClue I don't understand what you're saying... He says he has a format like X and Y and I'm assuming those are the only formats he has. Isn't that reasonable?

Comment: Oh jeez. I misunderstood your post. I thought you were only testing for those exact things. As in, exactly those two dates.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about speed, you should just test against the Regex "^\D" (not a digit) because as soon as it hits the "M" in "May..." it will fail. This will fail quickly and only run the minimum amount of times. You might also consider just getting a substring of the first character in the string and trying to convert it to an int and if it fails, then the same thing is true. By keeping the Regex short like that however, speed shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: but once this /[a-z]/i.test(1370039735000) hits data type of Number , won't it fail on contact?

Comment: Indeed it will, but anyway @adeneo's answer is probably better than both of our regex answers. ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Vache. Your solution is appreciated too!

Comment: Yeah, Regex isn't the simplest solution, but since Regex was requested that's what I described. Adeneo's suggestion of using isNaN is definitely the cleanest solution.